# Dockerfile can't find app.py

Tags: python, docker

I have the following folder structure in a flask app that I am embedding in a docker image.

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── db
│   ├── imgcomp
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
│       ├── comparison_result.html
│       ├── display_images.html
│       ├── index.html
│       └── upload.html
├── docker-compose.yml
├── requirements.txt
└── tests
```

These are the contents of the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
    build: .
    ports:
       - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
       - .:/code
```

These are the contents of Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

When I run docker-compose up, I get the error:

```
web_1  | python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Simply because its in the subfolder. Changing the argument to app/app.py doesn't help. Also, when I run docker-compose down, then edit the file, it doesn't seem to be registering any changes to the file when I run docker-compose up again. What am I missing?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to run Flask apps using the `flask` command, e.g. `flask run`?

Comment: Only if its a package. You can also start it like nodejs using app.py as the starter script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the same problem in [issue 1616](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1616#issuecomment-116879169)

> the issue appears to primarily be a consequence of the ADD/WORKDIR in the Dockerfile:

```
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
```

> Conflicting with the volume mapping in the docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
 - .:/code
```

> I may have misread the instructions but had both.

The reason:

> When running an app on a remote host, you'll need to remove any `volumes` entries that mount anything in from a local directory.
>
> The reason we promote both adding your code to the image and mounting it as a volume is so that doing a `docker-compose build` gets you an image that's ready to deploy to a remote server, but whose code can still be mounted when developing locally so it can be live-reloaded.
>
> If you want to use Compose to both develop an app locally and deploy it to the cloud, the best practice is to have a file for each - `docker-compose.yml` for local development and something else (e.g. `remote.yml`) for remote deployment - and use the `-f` flag to pass the alternate file in when deploying.
>
> You can use the [`extends` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to reduce duplication between both files.

---

On Windows, be careful about your path and its shared state: see [issue 3157](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3157#issuecomment-198328642).

Comment: Note that using an onguild python image would do the COPY for you: https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/150#issuecomment-255869639

Answer (score 4):

**For windows:**

One solution is removing the ***"volume"*** in your ***"docker-compose.yml"***.

The problem is, it will not update/sync your files in your host. (That is my case)
I tried playing around with volumes and found out that the ***"."*** in volume (***".:/code"***) is not working. It makes my code directory in docker empty.

What I would suggest to do is transfer your project in ***C:/Users/YourUsername/*** (Can be a deeper directory, as long it's under the path), then in ***volume*** parameter in docker-compose, change the ***".:/code"*** to ***"C:/Users/YourUsername/project_folder:/code"***